# Desktop.isDesktopSupported returning null in windows

Tags: api, desktop

I have the following code

```
    desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    url = new URL("http://www.facebook.com");
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(url.toURI());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and desktop is returning null for Windows 7. Can anyone suggest what to be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's not working with Windows 7 (it worked at me), but Desktop can return false negatives anyway. I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557207/2-apps-in-the-same-jre-are-getting-different-result-from-java-awt-desktop-isdes) and the only way around I could find, is opening the system browser the hard way, using java.lang.Runtime

for windows, your code will be

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
```

a very nice fully working code that covers OSX and Linux too can be be found [here](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#isDesktopSupported%28%29):

```
public static boolean isDesktopSupported()
```

*Tests whether this class is supported on the current platform. If it's supported, use getDesktop() to retrieve an instance.*

*Returns:
`true` if this class is supported on the current platform; `false` otherwise*

To make it short:
Windows 7 does not support this class

- See also: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201722/java-desktop-getdesktop-browseuri-is-supported-but-does-not-open-document)
- See also: [desktop api documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Comment: Sorry but I don't know a workaround for this problem