# 2 apps in the same JRE, are getting different result from java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, awt, liferay

I have a Maven Project that uses `java.awt.Desktop`. I'm using it for Google Authentication, so I need some way to open a browser dialog for Google Login, and user confirmation.

I'm exporting that library in a .jar file, that I intend to include it in lots of Liferay Portlets, in WEB-INF/lib

If I test the standalone project, running from the Liferay's Tomcat jre, Everything works fine, and `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` returns **true**.

When a portlet, deployed on the **Same Tomcat**, calls the same library function, the `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` returns **false**.

Since in both cases, I'm using the **Same Java Environment**, why am I getting a **different behavior**?

Also, if you know an alternative way to open a browser window instead of using Desktop.browse, it would be nice to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why it's not working in Servlet/PortletContext.

A workaround is opening the os browser with Java.lang.Runtime, as demonstated [here](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/)