# How to open a directory on a networked computer with Java

Tags: java

i already tried with this.

```
    String userHomePath = "\\mysvr\\project\\my Team\\001 test\\001 test\\003 Report";
    File userHome = new File(userHomePath);
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(userHome);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Why it can't open? Plz explain me. Because of white spaces? if so, how can i fix it. Thanks

Here's exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:////mysvr/project/my%20Team/001%20test/001%20test/003%20Report/. Error message: The system cannot find the file specified.
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.ace.insurance.fire.renewal.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

i can open till "\mysvr\project" .

Comment: Have you tried \\\\mysvr\\project\\?

Comment: Please post the stack trace or a description of the problem other than that it won't open.

Comment: No, just four backslashes for the first one - `\\\\mysvr\\project\\my Team` etc.

Comment: This is odd -- the error message indicates that something did a URL encoding on the filename, and I didn't think `new File()` would do that.

Comment: Can you open that path using the underlying OS?  Java says it can't find the file - are you sure you have it correct in the code?

Comment: i can open that path using the underlying OS. @Paul

Comment: Personally, what I'd do instead of guessing at the right way to specify the location is throw together a little Swing app and using JFileChooser, navigate to and select the location.  In other words, let Java tell you what it thinks the path to the location is.

Comment: @Paul, i dun want to use JFileChooser, plz tell me a way to open the path , Thanks.

Comment: I provided an answer below.  I was not suggesting you use JFileChooser as part of your application, just that you use it to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"//mysvr/project/..."` or `"\\\\mysvr\\project\\..."`.

Of course first try it out in a Windows Explorer. Doubling any backslash in a Java String literal.

Comment: Split the problem in parts: try `String files = userHome.list();`. And then try `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(userHome.toURL());`. However I saw now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201722/java-desktop-getdesktop-browseuri-is-supported-but-does-not-open-document

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   String userHomePath = "\\\\mysvr\\project\\my Team\\001 test\\001 test\\003 Report";
File userHome = new File(userHomePath);
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(userHome);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can reach the server from Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Include quotes as part of the path:

```
String userHomePath = "\"\\mysvr\\project\\my Team\\001 test\\001 test\\003 Report\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

With the **addition** of `//mysvr/project/...` or `\\\\mysvr\\project\\...` as @Joop Eggen (and other already) mentioned your code works on me also.

Without the double forward slash it don't. So either check the **availability** of the folder in explorer and if it is available (or exist etc).

If both conditions are met then I don't know what else to suggest.

P.S. The exception thrown for both cases is the same: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Curious: did you try with spaces in the path? I have that itching idea that the spaces is what makes and breaks it for the OP.

Comment: Well then, that makes the answer easy: the OS is not lying and the path -really- does not exist :)