# Blank JFrame when program is run

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am an absolute beginner in coding. I would like to know why is my Jframe blank when run, how do I fix it. From what I have research on the internet it seems that I should put the component inside the JFrame as it is empty but how do I do it

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUp1j.png)

```
public class Video extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {

final URI uri = new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rl0YiZjTqpw");

class OpenUrlAction implements ActionListener 
{
  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    open(uri);
  }
}

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Links");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(410, 400);
Container container = frame.getContentPane();
container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JButton btnclickHereTo = new JButton();
btnclickHereTo.setText("<HTML> <FONT color=\"#000099\"><U>Click Here To Watch Video</U></FONT>");
btnclickHereTo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
btnclickHereTo.setBorderPainted(false);
btnclickHereTo.setOpaque(false);
btnclickHereTo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
btnclickHereTo.setToolTipText(uri.toString());
btnclickHereTo.addActionListener(new OpenUrlAction());
container.add(btnclickHereTo);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
private static void open(URI uri) 
{
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
    {
      try 
      {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
      }
      catch (IOException e) 
      { /* TODO: error handling */ }
    }
    else
    { /* TODO: error handling */ }
  }

}
```

Comment: From the flagging options - "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Comment: btw: your code should be a copy-pastable text and not a screenshot

Comment: You could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201722, which seems to be related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setVisible(boolean b) {
```

Why would you override the `setVisible(...)` method of your frame? There is no reason to do that.

> I am an absolute beginner in coding

Start with something basic, like the example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

Keep a reference to the tutorial link handy since it contains information and examples for all Swing basics.

Comment: I have delete that part so what can i do to make it show

Comment: @DarenLua, read the tutorial for a working example. There is also example code for using the "Desktop" API. You need to spend time reading to learn Swing.